# React native paper Appbar.Header not styling properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a chat app and I wanted to have a custom header. I am using React Navigation that is working fine and the header is functioning properly but not styling properly. I am using React Native Paper for custom header. My code is ( just copied from website to make sure that everyone thing works fine which obviously not ):

```
<Appbar.Header>
    <Appbar.BackAction />
    <Appbar.Content title="Title" subtitle="Subtitle" />
    <Appbar.Action icon="magnify" />
    <Appbar.Action icon="dots-vertical" />
</Appbar.Header>
```

It is supposed to work like this:
[image: Picture of header on React Native Paper website]
But on my Android Device it look like this:
[image: Picture of header on My Android Device]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some padding to the Appbar.Header like this:

```
<Appbar.Header style={{padding:40}}>
    <Appbar.BackAction />
    <Appbar.Content title="Title" subtitle="Subtitle" />
    <Appbar.Action icon="magnify" />
    <Appbar.Action icon="dots-vertical" />
</Appbar.Header>
```

Working Example on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/react-native-paper-header)

Comment: Just after a little bit tweeking I got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)